# Firebase firestore is not fetching correct output when a query is made

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore Db where list of user's emails are stored, also have a form for user to fill and submit where **there is a check for existing email.**

**JS CODE**

```
 db.collection( 'emails' ).where( email.value,'!=', 'DbEmail' ).onSnapshot( ( querySnapshot ) =>
    {
      if ( querySnapshot.empty )
      {
        console.log( 'new record' )
      }
      else 
      {
        console.log( 'old record.' )
      }
```

Whenever the query is executed, it works fine giving the correct output -

> new record

when I enter an email that is not in available in the Db.

**ISSUE:**

When I enter an existing email I get **the same output** i.e. *'new record'* which is **incorrect.**

It should execute 'old record' but it is not happening.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please share some more code to understand the aspects.

Comment: the main piece of code is this with regards to the issue , rest is a simple if statement that checks whether the email input field is blank or not.

Comment: If `DbEmail` is a variable, you should call it without quotes to pas its value to `where`. So `db.collection( 'emails' ).where( email.value,'!=', DbEmail ).onSnapshot(...`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding there are two errors in your code:

1/ The signature of the `where()` method is as follows:

```
where ( fieldPath :  string | FieldPath ,  opStr :  WhereFilterOp ,  value :  any ) : Query < T >
```

2/ You want to check if a given email already exists so you should use the `"=="` operator.

---

So IMO you should change it to:

```
db.collection('emails').where('DbEmail', '==', email.value ).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No record corresponding to this email')
    }
    else {
        console.log('A record with this email already exists.')
    }
});
```